# Java - create and move xml : cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, xml, file-io, java-8

I create xml file as following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
            try {
                dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
                //add elements to Document
                Element rootElement = doc.createElement("document");
                //append root element to document
                doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // Répertoire de destination
            Element typeDoc = doc.createElement("typeDocument");
            typeDoc.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("En Attente"));
            rootElement.appendChild(typeDoc);

            // métadonnées :
            Element properties = doc.createElement("properties");
            rootElement.appendChild(properties);

            if (typo != null && !typo.isEmpty()) {
                // 3) Type de document (name-type-value)
                Element typoProperty = doc.createElement("property");
                properties.appendChild(typoProperty);
                Element typoName = doc.createElement("name");
                typoName.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("os:typologie"));
                typoProperty.appendChild(typoName);
                Element typoType = doc.createElement("type");
                typoType.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("d:text"));
                typoProperty.appendChild(typoType);
                Element typoValue = doc.createElement("value");
                typoValue.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(typo));
                typoProperty.appendChild(typoValue);
            }

            ......


            //for output to file, console
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            //for pretty print
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            logger.debug("nom xml: {}", xmlFolder + "/" + newFileName + ".xml");
            //write to console or file
            // StreamResult console = new StreamResult(System.out);
            StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(new File(xmlFolder + "/" + newFileName + ".xml")));
            //write data
            // transformer.transform(source, console);
            transformer.transform(source, file);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Erreur création XML: {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            return false;
        }
```

this file is created in specific folder. This folder is scanned by a java process that starts by moving the xml file:

```
  try {
        String path = dayDate != null ? destinationParentFolderPath + "/" + destinationFolderName + "/" + dayDate + "-" + file.getName() 
                                      : destinationParentFolderPath + "/" + destinationFolderName + "/" + file.getName();
        logger.debug("moveFileToWorkFolder: " + path);
        return Files.move(file.toPath(), FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.debug("Error moveFileToWorkFolder: " +  ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        e.printStackTrace ();
        return null;
    }
```

But I still get the following message :

```
Error moveFileToWorkFolder: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\alfresco\SCAN\152712_inconnu 51_DOCUMENTS ADM.xml -> C:\alfresco\SCAN\DOC_WORK\152712_inconnu 51_DOCUMENTS ADM.xml: Le processus ne peut pas accéder au fichier car ce fichier est utilisé par un autre processus.
```

=> Translate : cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

The folder is scanned every 20 seconds and after few tries, the xml is well copied
I don't understand why the file is locked and how to solve the issue...

Comment: did u open your xml in some editor or file explorer? Close your xml everywhere and repeat process.

Comment: Try to close the `FileOutputStream`  once the writing is finished.

Comment: @MaciejPulikowski no the xml was closed everywhere.

Comment: @Berger it works !

Answer (score 1):

It works by closing    FileOutputStream

```
   FileOutputStream outFile = null;
        try {
              ...
               outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(xmlFolder + "/" + newFileName + ".xml"));
                StreamResult file = new StreamResult(outFile);
                transformer.transform(source, file);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Erreur création XML: {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                outFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.debug("Erreur close FileOutputStream: {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
```